# What does regex <<set:[A-Z]>> mean in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I read a c# code, I don't understand regex pattern.

```cs
string name = Regex.Replace(opts[2] ?? "", @"<<set:[A-Z]+>>", "");
```

What does `@<<set:[A-Z]+>>` mean?

Is there pattern using `<<set:` ?

I understand this sentence that if `opts[2]` is `<<set:anithing>>something`, `name` set `something`.

Is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

You can find a detailed answer on sites where you can test regular expressions, like this one: https://regex101.com/r/9OWhtd/1

- <<set: matches the characters <<set: literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]

- matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

- Then >> matches the characters >> literally (case sensitive)

So it matches a string like `<<set:ABC>>` and replaces that with an empty string in your case.